# PHP - is there any way to quickly parse such text?

Tags: php

In PHP is there any quick way to get the names and values from this?

```
<!--AUTHCODE=VITAL5--><!--szSerialNumber=111222333444--><!--szTransactionAmount=1900--><!--szAuthorizationDeclinedMessage=--><!--szAVSResponseCode=N--><!--szAVSResponseMessage=Card authorized, no address or zip code match.--><!--szOrderNumber=1--><!--szAuthorizationResponseCode=000067--><!--szReturnCode=1--><!--szCVV2ResponseCode=--><!--szCVV2ResponseMessage=--><!--szIsApproved=1--><!--szTransactionFileName=9802850951761.009--><!--szCAVVResponseCode=-->
```

Comment: Yes, using a regular expression for example. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes, that's pretty easy to do. You want us to do it for you or help you with any trouble with your implementation so far?

Comment: Do we need to make a regex.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @webbiedave [Now we have two problems](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$text = "<!--AUTHCODE=VITAL5--><!--szSerialNumber=111222333444-->";
preg_match_all('/<!--([^=]+)=(.*?)-->/', $text, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

It will give you all the names and values.